# Start procces than return to main wioth wating to finish python

Tags: python

I want to start multiple programs in background witch run forever till i want to stop it in the main program. I have tried a lot of way like subprocces.Popen, but dosen't work very well, also read about, and try multiple threading, but can't made it to work.

This is my best solution so far:

```
def star_proc_1():
    os.system('START /B start_some_2.exe')
def start_proc_2():
    os.system('START /B start_some_1.exe')
def stop_proc_1():
    os.system('taskkill /F /IM start_some_1.exe')
def stop_proc_2():
    os.system('taskkill /F /IM start_some_2.exe')

while True:
    op = raw_input('$:')
    if op == 'start FTP':
        star_proc_1()
    elif op == 'start HTTP':
        start_proc_2()
    elif op == 'stop FTP':
        stop_proc_1()
    elif op == 'stop HTTP':
        stop_proc_2()
    elif op == 'exit':
        sys.exit()
```

But it's dont work so well. Can some one show a beter way with multiple threading, or a god tutorial which explain how should i do this?

Comment: *"dosen't work very well,"* is not very informative. What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Could you provide a [minimal complete code example that reproduces the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

`os.system` will block until the spawned process completes, if you want to start a subprocess without blocking, you can use the `subprocess` module: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html